# Next.js how send 200 status to client in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, xmlhttprequest, next.js

I need to transfer status from the server to the client if I receive status 200 without content for getMainPage request. How can i do this?
I tried (example from google):

```
if (ctx.res) ctx.res.statusCode = 404;
        return {notFound: true};
```

ctx.res always = undefined

/*main page.ts*/

```
IndexPage.getInitialProps = async (ctx: IExtendedAppContext): Promise<IPageProps> => {
const { reduxStore } = ctx;
const regionId = reduxStore.getState().regions.current?.id;
const cityId = reduxStore.getState().regions.current?.city;
const transaction = apm?.startTransaction('IndexPage');
const main: IMain = await reduxStore.dispatch(getMainPage({ region: regionId, city: cityId }, transaction));
const span = startSpan('fetchAlphabetList', transaction);
const alphabetList = await alphabetListService.fetch({ region: regionId, city: cityId })
    .finally(() => endSpan(span));
endTransaction(transaction);

return { pageMeta: main.page_meta, alphabetList };
};
```

/*with-redux-store.tsx*/

```
export type Store = ReturnType<typeof getOrCreateStore>;

interface IProps {
    reduxStore: Store;
    initialReduxState: Store;
}

export interface IExtendedAppContext extends NextPageContext {
    reduxStore: Store;
}

export interface IInitialProps extends AppContext {
    ctx: IExtendedAppContext;
}
```

getMainPage request and all get requests uses that get method

```
public async get(entity: string, query: object, pathVariables: string[] | number[] = [], cookies: string = '') {
        const queryURI = makeURIParams(query);
        const key = makeQueryKey(entity, query, pathVariables);
        try {
            const localCopy = await this.getLocalCopy(key);
            return this.handleResponse(localCopy);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(this.getUrlAPI(entity, queryURI, pathVariables));
            return this.fetch(this.getUrlAPI(entity, queryURI, pathVariables), {headers: {...this.getCookies(cookies)}})
                .then(this._httpHandler).then(async (dataJSON: any) => {
                try {
                    const { meta = {} } = dataJSON;
                    meta.requestDate = getCurrentTime();
                    const { expire, date } = meta;
                    if (expire <= date) {
                        await this.purgeStorageByKey(key);
                        return dataJSON;
                    }
                    if (expire !== 0) await this.setLocalCopy(key, JSON.stringify(dataJSON));
                    return dataJSON;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(this.getUrlAPI(entity, queryURI, pathVariables), error);
                    return null;
                }
            }).then(this.handleResponse).catch((error: Error) => {
                console.log(this.getUrlAPI(entity, queryURI, pathVariables), error);
                return null;
            });
        }
    }
```

/*method where we can get request's status*/

```
private _httpHandler(response: Response): Promise<IResponse | null> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            if ((response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) || response.status === 403) {
                try {
                    const json = await response.json();
                    resolve({ requestUrl: response.url, responseHeaders: response?.headers, ...json });
                } catch (_) {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            } else {
                reject(response.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you need alphabetList response status code ?

Comment: @n1koloza oh no, I need getMainPage, i forgot to mention

Comment: can you show how looks getMainPage ?

Comment: @n1koloza i updated question

Answer (score 0):

so if it is async function and returns value, you can check status,

```
let mainResponseStatus = false;
    if (main.status === 200) {
     mainResponseStatus = true;
    }
```

and then continue your code and return whatever you want but defense it in return

```
return {
    somethingToReturn: mainResponseStatus ? returnWhatYouWant : []
}
```

Comment: If you propose to do this in getInitialProps, then the main has such an object and the status field is not there

Comment: if 404 then main will be just {}

Comment: But checking for {} is not very good, since the status of 200 without content, in theory, will not be equal to {}

Comment: return from getMainPage,or use try catch or make it in useEffect

Comment: I did it, I still need to transfer this status to ctx.res.statusCode = main.status but ctx.res always = undefined how i can do it or on localhost it doesn't work?